# Firefox: box-sizing and min-height

Tags: html, css, firefox

I can’t understand: is this really a bug or am I just missing out something?

I have `box-sizing: border-box` set for all my div within an HTML document (with all the `-moz` and `-webkit` prefixes, of course). So it means the `height` of a div always includes its `padding`. It’s reasonable to expect the `min-height` property to act similarly. But apparently, in Firefox it doesn’t.

I mean, when I have a div with no `height` set (i.e. `height: auto`), but with a `min-height` (say, 220px) and `padding` (say, 10px), it results in the overall height of the div being 240px instead of 220 in Firefox! It stays alright either way in Chrome and Opera, though.

Shouldn’t this be fixed, or is it some sort of a feature which I don’t get?

Comment: Well, quirksmode.org mentions that box-sizing doesn't work with min-height/min-width - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html (about halfway down the page). I'm not really sure why this is though.

Comment: That's very strange, because max-width does honour box-sizing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> …is this really a bug…
>   Shouldn’t this be fixed, or is it some
>   sort of a feature which I don’t get?

[It will](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243412) be fixed (it's a bug not a feature).
But for now you should vote on this [**bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308801).
If it's any consolation `min-/max-width` seems to be working just fine though.

Comment: The Firefox team is arguing whether or not it should actually be in the CSS UI CR and want to pursue their own implementation of `padding-box`. This is Netscape 4 deja vu.

Comment: [IT HAS BEEN FIXED](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/17?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Firefox_17_for_developers#CSS).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [Modernizr test](https://github.com/riddla/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/padding-added-to-minheight.js) to detect this constellation (`min-height`, `padding` and `box-sizing: border-box`). You can [read more](http://volker-rose.de/blog/box-sizing-and-min-height-css-trouble-within-firefox/) about it over at my blog or see a [JSFiddle with the test and a fix applied](http://jsfiddle.net/4bP73/).