# Need I worry about bugs in old FF versions?

Tags: css, firefox

As per Paul Irish's [advice](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) I'm using `border-box` box sizing with a universal selector.

As part of my effort to make my site able to handle increased font sizes set by visually impaired users, I've set my `header` dimensions with `em`. It also has `min-width` and `min-height` set, but in pixels, in order that the heading block won't shrink below given minimums if the user shrinks the font.

The problem is I read that Firefox up until version 17 has a [`border-box` with min/max height bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308801) (also in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984038/firefox-box-sizing-and-min-height)). Given that I now have FF 30 on my machine, which I assume is common, should I be worrying about a FF browser bug from two years ago?

Just because browsershots.org and browserstack.com offer screenshots for old FF, should I worry about them? I hear about people on intranets being stuck with IE 6, 7 or 8, but might this apply to Firefox? I read that, by default, Firefox is set to [automatically update itself](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version).

(I don't think my site targets a particular enough audience to able to hazard a guess about what they'd be using or from where/with what they will be viewing.)

If I should implement a workaround for this bug, none of suggestions I've seen involve simply setting `box-sixing` back to `content-box` only for the `header`, and then adjusting its dimenions to suit. Can I simply do that?

It seems I may also be subject to an old FF [background-image-not-displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15335718/1898641) bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201406-201407), this is the use of old Firefox versions (July 2014):

```
Version | 2.0 | 3.0 | 3.5 | 3.6 | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12  | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16
   ‰    | .2  | .8  | .2  | 1.6 | .4 | .3 | .4 | .2 | .6 | .3 | .7 | .6 | 1.4 | .6 | .6 | .8 | 1.1
```

Suming them all, it's 10.8 ‰ = 1.08 %

It's you who should decide if it's worth implementing a workaround for those 1% or not.